# Open access datasets for QTL analysis?

Tags: human-genetics, database, data, quantitative-genetics

I'm just getting started out learning how to use the QTL package in R studio, and I'm trying to find additional datasets to practice with. I've already worked through the datasets [here](http://www.rqtl.org/tutorials/) on the Rqtl website. Is there anywhere I can find similar datasets to work with? I'm specifically looking to work with autosomal data.